# A fallacious proof of the existece of non-Borel sets.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, fake-proofs, borel-sets

Let $\lambda$ be Lebesgue-Borel measure and suppose that $\lambda(X)$ is defined for every $X\subset[0,1]$, in which case $\lambda(X) \in [0,1]$ by monotonicity. Define the set $B$ by

$$B=\{\lambda(X):X\subset[0,1], \lambda(X)\not\in X\}$$

It is a subset of $[0,1]$. Upon testing $\lambda(B)$ for membership in $B$ we find that the statements $\lambda(B)\in B$ and $\lambda(B)\not \in B$ are equivalent, a contradiction. Hence some $X\subset[0,1]$ is not Borel.

What is the problem in this Russell's paradox flavoured proof?

In my opinion the proof merely shows that, under the the hypothesis that every subset of $[0,1]$ is measurable, such set $B$ cannot exist, not that the initial hypothesis is false.

EDIT: $\lambda:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\to [0,\infty]$ is assumed to be the Lebesgue-Borel measure, with all its known properties. The question is whether $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Presumably you want $\lambda([0,1])=1$ and more generally, for $a\leq b,$ $\lambda([a,b])=b-a.$

Comment: Why doesn’t this argument work if $$\lambda(X)=\begin{cases}0&1\notin X\\1&1\in X\end{cases}$$ This *in* a measure on $[0,1]$

Comment: If you mean $\lambda(X)$ to be the Lebesgue measure of $X$, for every $t \in [0,1]$ we have $t = \lambda([0,t))$ with $t \notin [0,t)$, so $B = [0,1]$.  $\lambda(B) = 1 \in B$, but that's not a contradiction, because $1 = \lambda([0,1)$ also.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are absolutely right. $\lambda(B) \in B$ does not lead to a contradiction. I overlooked the statement that $\lambda(B) \in B$ implies  $\lambda(B) \not \in B$, which is false. Although the statement  $\lambda(B) \not \in B$ implies  $\lambda(B) \in B$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lambda(B)\in B\tag{1}$$ just means that there is some $C$ such that $\lambda(C)=\lambda(B)$ and $\lambda(C)\notin C.$

For example, if singletons all have measure $0,$ then  every $\lambda(X)\in B.$ Because you can use $C=X \setminus\{\lambda(X)\}.$

So there is no contradiction in $(1).$

Comment: Indeed ! We have that $\lambda(B)\not \in B$ implies $\lambda(B) \in B$, so  $\lambda(B) \in B$. But from $\lambda(B) \in B$ we cannot deduce $\lambda(B)\not \in B$. Thanks a lot I overlooked the converse.

Comment: So in the end we just have $\lambda(B)\in B$, no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't even justified:

> Upon testing $\lambda(B)$ for membership in $B$ we find that the statements $\lambda(B)\in B$ and $\lambda(B)\not \in B$ are equivalent...

How?

Note that you only assume that $\lambda$ is a monotonic function, not that it's the real Lebesgue-Borel measure. Okay, let us define $\lambda(X)=0$ for all $X$. Then for $X=\{1\}$, we have $\lambda(X)\not\in X$, so $\lambda(X)=0\in B$. In fact, $B=\{0\}$. And it turns out that $\lambda(B)\in B$.

Comment: $\lambda$ is assumed to be the Lebesgue-Borel measure.

Comment: @Alphie I understand. The point is that **if** the argument were sound, it would apply to all monotonic functions, because that's the only property of $\lambda$ that it purports to use. Therefore we can locate the flaws in the argument by applying it to other monotonic functions. And it's best to choose simple counterexamples.